# Australian post code/area shapefiles

Tags: data-request, geocoding, postal-code, australia, geospatial

I'm looking for the Shapefile of the Australian Postcodes/area 4-digits. I would prefer an open source if possible.

Comment: https://www.psma.com.au/products/postcode-boundaries remember though they change from time to time. You might need to purchase the data or pay some sort of licensing fee.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Australian Bureau of Statistics, [exact geographic boundaries for the post codes are not well defined](http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/D3310114.nsf/home/Frequently+Asked+Questions#Anchor20). Indeed, the data available from the ABS are re-released periodically. However for simple purposes you can probably find what you need [from the ABS geography portal](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.003July%202016?OpenDocument).

Always carefully read the data descriptions of course to make sure it's fit for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it here at Australian Statistical Geography Standard (ASGS)
https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026/access-and-downloads/digital-boundary-files